# Converting Mongo ID to String to do Comparison

Tags: javascript, mongodb, tostring

I have a search feature that returns filtered data from my mongoDB based on a user's input for various filters. So, for instance I can do this and it works:

```
if (lastName) {
    let arrlastName = [];
    arrlastName = lastName.split(",");
    _.each(arrlastName, (l, key, c) => {
        arrlastName[key] = new RegExp(arrlastName[key], "i");
    });
    search['name.last'] = { $in: arrlastName };
}
```

The above returns a filtered data set where the results match whatever was passed in by the user in a comma separated list.

However, I am running into a challenge in comparing a user inputed value with an `_id` value in our mongo db. Of course, the `_id` I'm checking against here is not a string, but a mongo objectId -- that's the issue as far as I can tell. So I'm trying to figure out how I can convert either the input, or the `_id`, or both, to do a valid comparison. This was the initial code:

```
if (person) search['_id'] = person;
```

That doesn't work, because the value for `person` here is a string, and `_id` is not -- as I said, `_id` is a mongo objectId. So how can I do a type conversion to handle this check?

I tried this but it causes errors:

```
if (person) search['_id'].toString() = person;
```

What would the syntax look like for this kind of comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mongoDB you can use `ObjectId.valueOf()`

[From the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/)

```
ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").valueOf()
```

will return the following string:

```
507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I also pass in the property name dynamically? Like so: ObjectId("_id").valueOf()? If not, I'm not clear how this would solve my particular issue.

Comment: Then it would have to be :  `ObjectId(x).valueOf()` where `x` is a variable whose value is an ObjectID string like "507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e".

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated, @Sebastien!